# Redirect all outgoing traffic on port 80 to a different IP on the same server

Tags: linux, routes, ip, iptables

I have multiple IP addresses on the same server and I would like to redirect all outgoing traffic on port 80 to a different IP on the same server just no to use always main IP.

Currently I'm using this:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP;
```

and it works well, but it redirects everything and when I make backups over SSH backup it's failing.

System: CentOS 5.8 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP
```

Comment: Is it both ways? like incoming and outgoing?